# responsive css width with %

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Im a beginner in css, and i have tried to find the answer in ebook and google, but i couldnt find it. So please bear with me :D

I want to create a responsive web, so this is my `meta` tag :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

This is a part of my code, which containt an image with a big width :

```
<div id="desc">
        <img alt="" src="images/MallDetail/MallDesc.png">
</div>
```

To make this **image fit with the current screen**, i tried to make it as big as the current screen's width with the css. However, the following code is **NOT** working :

```
#desc {
    width: 100%;
}
```

So, i tried this css and its **working** :

```
#desc img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

My question is, why the first css code is not working?it should be same as the second one. Is it related to the %?or the `meta` tag i have above?

Thaks for your time :D

Comment: `it should be same as the second one` Why do you think that?  What do you think `img` means?

Comment: The first css code change the width of the <div> but does not change the width of the image. The second changes the width of the <img> to 100% thats why its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the first css rule you're assigning a width of 100% to the div element (which is already 100% wide by default, as a block element) but the image is an inline-replaced element by default, thus it won't extend its width.

In the second rule you're assigning instead the width to the image, so the resulting effect is to stretch the image.

Answer (score 4):

`#desc` matches the `<div>` and does not affect the `<img>`.

Comment: This is right. Here is a quick [demo](http://jsbin.com/odobic/1) you can [play with](http://jsbin.com/odobic/1/edit).

Comment: Thanks for your help :D Its too bad i only can choose one answer :D

Answer (score 1):

The first CSS snippet says that the element with id `desc` should have width 100%.  The second says that `img` elements inside of the element with id `desc` should have width 100%.  If you make some other modification to the first snippet, e.g., adding a background color to the element with id `desc`, you'll see that it (the element with id `desc`) is indeed being affected by the CSS;  it has 100% width.

Comment: Thanks for your help :D Its too bad i only can choose one answer :D

Answer (score 1):

In first, you make the width of container `div` `100%`. But `width` property is not `inherited` (unlike some other css properties), so `img` is not `100%` in first one.

In second one, you made the `width` of `img` `100%`. Parent take the `width` of child elements. And also, `div` is block element, so container `div` is also `100%` , along with `img` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your help :D Its too bad i only can choose one answer :D